# How to execute unix command after few background jobs are completed?

Tags: unix, tcsh

My c-shell code has to complete few concurrent background jobs before execution of some unix commands. However, somehow in code my background jobs never returns handle to unix commands.

i.e.

```
    $cmd1 | tee $XD/m1.log&
    $cmd2 | tee $XD/m2.log&
    $cmd3 | tee $XD/m3.log&
    $cmd4 | tee $XD/m4.log&
```

All 4 commands mentioned above generate 4 different files named `$L1`,`$L2`,`$L3` and `$L4` (example: `setenv L1 $XD/div.txt` etc.). I need to merge all of these files after removing the first line from them so have used following logic. But seems like sed command never gets executed

```
   wait $!
   echo "Job completed"
   sed -i '1d' $L2
   sed -i '1d' $L3
   sed -i '1d' $L4
   cat $L1 $L2 $L3 $L4 >> $L
```

Could you please help me to make then executes post background jobs?

tried

```
if (! -e $L4 ) then 
   if ( -f $L4 ) then 
       wait $!
       echo "Job completed"
       sed -i '1d' $L2
       sed -i '1d' $L3
       sed -i '1d' $L4
       cat $L1 $L2 $L3 $L4 >> $L
   endif
endif
```

but didn't help either.

```
   $cmd1 | tee $XD/m1.log&
   $cmd2 | tee $XD/m2.log&
   $cmd3 | tee $XD/m3.log&
   $cmd4 | tee $XD/m4.log&

   if (! -e $L4 ) then 
     if ( -f $L4 ) then 
       wait $!
       echo "Job completed"
       sed -i '1d' $L2
       sed -i '1d' $L3
       sed -i '1d' $L4
       cat $L1 $L2 $L3 $L4 >> $L
     endif
   endif
```

Expected results would be to generate `$L` file (`$XD/final.txt`), which would happen only when script will be back to 2nd half section containing sed command.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, just use:

```
wait
```

`wait` without any parameter wait will wait for all children processes. `$!` is pid of the last background process started so `wait $!` will wait only for process last child process.

Long answer, full script edited:

```
#!/bin/env tcsh
set cmd1 = 'printf header\nline11\nline12\n'
set cmd2 = 'printf header\nline21\nline22\n'
set cmd3 = 'printf header\nline31\nline32\n'
set cmd4 = 'printf header\nline41\nline42\n'
set XD = '.'
set L = "${XD}/m.log"
set L1 = "${XD}/m1.log"
set L2 = "${XD}/m2.log"
set L3 = "${XD}/m3.log"
set L4 = "${XD}/m4.log"

touch "${L}" "${L1}" "${L2}" "${L3}" "${L4}" || exit (1)
( ${cmd1}; sleep 5 ) | tee "${L1}" &
( ${cmd2}; sleep 2 ) | tee "${L2}" &
( ${cmd3}; sleep 4 ) | tee "${L3}" &
( ${cmd4}; sleep 3 ) | tee "${L4}" &
wait
echo "Job completed"
cat "${L1}" > "${L}"
sed '1d' "${L2}" >> "${L}"
sed '1d' "${L3}" >> "${L}"
sed '1d' "${L4}" >> "${L}" 

exit (0)
```

Test:

```
% ./user3093942.tcsh
[1] 1542 1543
header
line11
line12
[2] 1545 1546
header
line21
line22
[3] 1548 1549
header
line31
line32
[4] 1551 1552
header
line41
line42
[4]  + Done                          ( ${cmd4}; sleep 3 ) | tee ./m4.log
[3]  + Done                          ( ${cmd3}; sleep 4 ) | tee ./m3.log
[2]  + Done                          ( ${cmd2}; sleep 2 ) | tee ./m2.log
[1]  + Done                          ( ${cmd1}; sleep 5 ) | tee ./m1.log
Job completed
% cat ./m.log
header
line11
line12
line21
line22
line31
line32
line41
line42
```